# PHPExcel Calculates Value Only After Opening Excel File

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Any insight on what might be the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Taking a simple example:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
   $objReader->setLoadAllSheets();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($directory);
   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
   $age = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C4')->getFormattedValue();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetByName('SheetName');
   $num1 =$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D5')->getOldCalculatedValue();
   $num2 =$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D6')->getOldCalculatedValue();
```

The value of age = 40 is correct. But the value of num1 = 0 & num2 = 0.

When i open the excel file , save and reload the page values num1 = 25 & num2 = 0.52 which are correct.

I tried changing getOldCalculatedValue() to getCalculatedValue() but the page doesn't load.

Answer (score 0):

Solved This Yesterday just remembered to get answer this.

This happens because PHP can't read a cells value that has an error.

The Ms Error blocks PHPExcel's ability to read the cells value through ->getCalculatedValue() = Error, getOldCalculatedValue() = 0 , getFormattedValue() = "Error with calculation -->CELLVAL --> CELLVAL-->".

To solve this, disable all errors on the workbook.

Excel -> Preferences ->Error Checking -> Disable checkbox 'Enable Background error checking' and the rules.

Save your file and work on that basis.

Comment: I thought this would work. And it did for one instance. But as a general overview, this method is not the Correct Way around this.